# Error in simple Java application

Tags: java, htmlunit

Just playing around with java trying to learn it etc.

Here is my code so far, using HtmlUnit.

```
package hsspider;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;

/**
 * @author 
 */
public class Main {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("starting ");
        Spider spider = new Spider();
        spider.Test();
    }
}


package hsspider;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
/**
 * @author 
 */
public class Spider {

    public void Test() throws Exception
    {
        final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://www.google.com");
        System.out.println(page.getTitleText());
    }
}
```

I am using Netbeans.

I can't seem to figure out what the problem is, why doesn't it compile?

The error:

```
C:\Users\mrblah\.netbeans\6.8\var\cache\executor-snippets\run.xml:45: 
Cancelled by user.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

The row in the xml is:

```
 <translate-classpath classpath="${classpath}" targetProperty="classpath-translated" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Test is declared to throw Exception. If you add "throws Exception" to your main method it should compile. For example:

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("starting ");
    Spider spider = new Spider();
    spider.Test();
}
```

Comment: isn't throwing an Exception at the main method rather bad style? Why not just catch the Exception and print an error message?

Comment: Sure it's bad style, but it.s certainly sufficient for a quick example for someone who just wants to know why their code isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

What Steve said is correct. But maybe there are some problems with the uppercase character of `Test`. A method always starts with a lower case character. So `test` would be better.

Comment: A method always starts with a lower case letter *by convention*. It is not required. Some conventions, for example, have private methods starting with an underscore.

Answer (score 1):

Unchecking the "Compile on Save" option of the "Properties" tab in Netbeans 7.1.2 resolved a similar error message for me.